# Canonical way to include an applet

Tags: java, applet, embed, next-generation-plugin

What is the canonical way to include the Applet?

I have tried,

Switch on Browsers in JS.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#javascript

This breaks in Safari 5.0.1 on Leopard. (It worked on Safari on Snow leopard.)

Since we are not supporting old brosers, I assumed I could just use `<object>` tag, but apparently FF wont respect that.

What is the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`applet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html#applet) tag seems like a reasonable compromise, but I've migrated almost entirely to [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).

Addendum: A passerby notes,

> JWS is a technology for launching desktop apps.

From the Java SE 6u10 release notes: "The next-generation Java Plug-In technology…provides support for launching applets directly from JNLP files."

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question. JWS is a technology for launching desktop apps.

Comment: @edoloughlin: Thank you for commenting. In this context, JWS may be considered part of a migration strategy. I've elaborated above.

Comment: @edoloughlin:  Since Sun/Oracle's "Next Generation" Plug-in 2 architecture JRE (1.6.0_10+), JWS can be used to configure **embedded** applets.  See the bottom two links of the [applet info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) for more details. @trashgod In that regard I was thinking of your marvelous [Alpha Composite Applet](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) and how it might benefit from both being able to be configured by form/JavaScript, yet able to export a PNG of the resulting image using the JNLP API file services.  ;)

Comment: "The next-generation Java Plug-In technology…provides support for launching applets directly from JNLP files." Actually that statement is slightly misleading.  JWS could launch applets free-floating since 1.2 when it was introduced.  It is since 1.6.0_10+ that they can remain *embedded* in a web page.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: Thank you for expanding on this. I started to ping you; how did you see the colloquy? The Alpha code has been stable for some time; feel free to fork it as needed.